# C# Opening form directly from code and getting input

Tags: c#

C# newbie here, I was wondering if there was a way to open a form in runtime, get the inputs from it, then close it. I am trying to create it as an object in runtime but can not access it.

```
var myForm1 = new myForm();
myForm1.Show();
```

However, though I created the form as another .cs file, I get a syntax error saying it can not be found. What am I missing? Or should I use something other than form?

EDIT:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ert
{
    public partial class ConnectionForm: Form
    {
        public BaglantiBilgileri()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Form's code, I have created it as a separate form.cs file

```
var myForm = new ConnectionForm();
```

This is inside my main executed code block, it is a separate .cs file, and it says type or namespace could not be found, am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the error, maybe post the error string? What cannot be found: the myForm class?

Comment: How do you read the value from the other form? can you show us the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide the error Message you get. Anyways opening a form at runtime and closing it when you have retrieved some data could be done like this:

```
using(Form myForm1 = new myForm())
{
    //Initialize the components of your form

    DialogResult result = myForm1 .ShowDialog();
    if(result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       //return whatever it is you want to return 
       //for example via a getter inside of myForm1
    }
}
```

The DialogeResult of the form is set automatically when you close the form but you can also set it programatically from inside your form:

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
```

after a specific event occured that makes you know when to retrieve the data.

Comment: The problem is, when i write "Form myForm1 = new myForm()" the IDE says myForm is not defined and underlines with red.

Comment: Try renaming the constructor "BaglantiBilgileri" to "ConnectionForm" because the constructor has to have the same name as the class he is the constructor of. Also make sure both classes have the same namespace.

Comment: Thanks so much, combining both answers worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the bellow line to the main form:

```
using ert;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, combining both answers worked for me